# Access RTP statistics current send package of call through python

Tags: asterisk, rtp, pjsip

When I simulate the call with zoiper, it can display the statistics contain current send bitrate in kb/s. Is there a way to get that value ?

Answer (score 0):

This feature is usless.

Asterisk have no VAD realisation, so bitrate is fixed and depend of used codec only.